# Oracle SQL Get Reference of third table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a database with 3 tables :

- PM_FLX_ENTE
- PM_ST
- PM_ANO_SP

and I would like to get `PM_ANO_SP.L_ANO_SP` for certain values of `PM_ANO_L.L_ANO` which contains a code number with `/`.

```
SELECT COUNT(RF_INTRN),TRIM(pm_st.c_st),TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO)
    FROM PM_FLX_ENTE
    INNER JOIN PM_ST ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ST = PM_ST.C_ST
    INNER JOIN PM_ANO_L ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ANO = pm_ano_l.c_ano
    WHERE pm_flx_ente.C_ANO <> '0000'
        AND pm_ano_l.c_lang = 'FR'
    group by TRIM(pm_st.c_st), TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO)
ORDER BY COUNT(RF_INTRN) DESC
```

[image: sql query result and pm_ano_sp table]
Can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit overkill, but if it's only Id in your `PM_ANO_SP`, then going straight for a join and working with what you get is a way :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(RF_INTRN),
    TRIM(NVL(PM_ANO_SP.L_ANO_SP, pm_st.c_st)), -- If found in PM_ANO_SP, use it
    TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO)
FROM PM_FLX_ENTE
INNER JOIN PM_ST 
    ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ST = PM_ST.C_ST
INNER JOIN PM_ANO_L 
    ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ANO = PM_ANO_L.C_ANO
LEFT JOIN PM_ANO_SP 
    ON PM_ST.C_ST = PM_ANO_SP.C_ST -- < Don't know the name
WHERE 
    pm_flx_ente.C_ANO <> '0000'
    AND pm_ano_l.c_lang = 'FR'
GROUP BY TRIM(pm_st.c_st), TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO)
ORDER BY COUNT(RF_INTRN) DESC
```

Comment: It's absolutely that i would, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add yet another condition into `WHERE` clause:

```
and instr(PM_ANO_L.L_ANO, '/') > 0
```